# CommandNotFound issue with my discord bot in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i'm playing with discord bots a little bit.
My issue is that when I type one of my commands, it doesn't work and shows me this message: "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "dadjoke" is not found" (this is an example but I have the same issue with all the commands I tried).

Here is my full code:

```py
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


#Setup the client
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    #connection
    print(f'Ready and Logged in as {client.user}')


#Help
@commands.command(name='help')
async def help(ctx):
    #Embed parameters
    Help_Embed = discord.Embed(title=f"</{client.user}y Help>", description=f"{client.user} bot by Stan_#1423", color=0xfee010)
    Help_Embed.add_field(name="Version code:", value="v0.1", inline=False)
    Help_Embed.add_field(name="Day Released:", value="03/03/22", inline=False)
    Help_Embed.add_field(name="Get a joke", value="type: '.dadjoke'", inline=True)
    #Sending Embed
    await ctx.send(embed=Help_Embed)


#Jokes
@commands.command(name='dadjoke')
async def dadjoke(ctx):
    headers = {'Accept': 'text/plain',}
    resp = requests.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', headers=headers)
    joke = resp.text
    await ctx.send(joke)


#Run the client
client.run('TOKEN')
```

I have already looked it up on the internet and i didn't find anything that solved my problem, i also tried to copy some code i found on online courses and stuff, but i still had the same problem.

Thanks for helping and sorry for bothering you guys with my dumb problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using prefixed commands, it should be
`@client.command(name=‘whatever’)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use `@client.command()` instead of `commands.command()`.